# LGD/PD Databases

Tags: default-probability

I am trying to compare LGD/PD for Banks and other financial institutions using different approach thank Merton. Are there any publicly available data on which I can build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re LGD: you can look at Mark-iT for ISDA Credit Event Auction settlements, here's a link actually
http://www.creditfixings.com/CreditEventAuctions/fixings.jsp

Obviously these will give recoveries as determined by bond auctions, varying according to SUB and SENIOR in the type of names you are looking at. These outcomes are a bit pathological for banks as SUB credit events sometimes had no deliverables given bail-ins, prior to the 2014 update to ISDA definitions, therefore $LGD = 1-R$ settled at 100% for SUB in several cases eg BES.

That may all be derivatives mumble swerve, clearly LGD on actual claims may vary from counterparty to counterparty where bilateral commutations maye have been agreed on a case by case basis (eg AIG), but it is a good demonstrable public source.

Re PDs I guess, (sadly) you have to go to ratings agencies but I don't have a link to hand.

Comment: Could you please comment more on how would you extract R using these data? Thank you.

Comment: sure, so let's pick a nice vintage :):

Comment: Final Results of the Ambac Financial Group  CDS Auction, 10 December 2010

Final Price: 9.5 **<- This is R, since this is the price at which bonds cleared**
On 10 December 2010, 14 dealers submitted initial markets, physical settlement requests and limit orders to the Ambac Financial Group auction administered by Creditex and Markit to settle trades across the market referencing Ambac Financial Group, Inc..

Relevant Currency
USD

Comment: In the same year we had capitulation in the Irish banking crisis, and:

Anglo Irish Bank Auction Results, 09 December 2010

Anglo Irish Bank CDS Subordinated Bucket2

Final Price: 18.25
Anglo Irish Bank CDS Subordinated Bucket3

Final Price: 18
Anglo Irish Bank CDS SNR/SUB Bucket1

Final Price: 74.5
Anglo Irish Bank CDS Senior Bucket2

Final Price: 76
Anglo Irish Bank CDS Senior Bucket3

Final Price: 74.5

Comment: The Final Prices, i.e. recoveries, are distributed across buckets governed by maturity, which can happen in a Restructuring type of default as opposed to a mere Failure to Pay (where recovery / Final Price is just one number). You could take some kind of average in this case as SNR / SUB are so different

Comment: sorry that copy pasted terribly: bottom line, Final Price = R

Comment: and this is the reference for the settlement of all credit derivative contracts (traded under market standard ISDA definitions), for the name in question, so I would say a pretty defensible mark - the website even shows the prices different dealers made in the auction for actual trades - these weren't LIBOR, but tradeable and traded levels. The caveat is, as mentioned, all of this does not mean that a specific trade will have this recovery applied given bilateral negotiations (of which there were myriad in the Lehman claims for example). But this might be good enough depending on your need

Comment: Excellent, thank you

Comment: no probs sir, best of luck!